# Add unique constraint by removing duplicates

Tags: mysql, algorithm, sql-delete

My mysql table looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE "my_table" (
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "content" blob NOT NULL,
  "business_id" varchar(255) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This table can contains several lines with the same "business_id". I want to make the business_id column unique. For this, I want to delete all lines which share a business_id except the last one.

For example, if I have the following lines

```
10  'hello' '5'
...
21  'hello' '5'
...
350 'hello' '5'
```

I want to delete lines of id 10 and 21.

I'm stuck on how to write the delete query. I don't know how to express that constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your DB before deletion:

```
delete FROM my_table where  business_id in 
    (select business_id from (select business_id from my_table group by business_id having count(business_id)>1) t) 
  and business_id not in 
    (select maxid from (select max(business_id) maxid from my_table group by business_id having count(business_id)>1) t1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected a bit the request but it gave me what I needed:
    delete FROM my_table where business_id in (select business_id        from (select business_id from my_table group by business_id having count(business_id)>1) t) 
  and id not in 
    (select maxid from (select max(id) maxid from my_table group by business_id having count(business_id)>1) t1);